# How to handle redefinition of Macro?

Tags: swig

My C code is like bellow.

// file.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define value 10
#define value 20
void  func()
{
    printf("%d\n",value);
}
```

My Interface file is like bellow.

```
//sample.i
%module sample
%{
    #include "func.c"
%}
%include "func.c"`
```

When I run the command  "swig -python sample.i", I am getting the error like bellow.
Macro 'value' redefined. The previous definition of  'value'  is there.

How to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting that swig considers it an error, but the compiler (mine anyway) considers it a warning.  If you can't fix the header, you can do:

```
//sample.i
%module sample
%{
    #include "func.c"
%}

#define value 20
void  func()
{
    printf("%d\n",value);
}
```

Basically, expand the header file inline and remove the offending line from swig processing.  Otherwise, fix the header.

Comment: Yes... GCC  considers it a warning.But If you undefine value 
(#undef value) before the next definition then SWIG gives warning and compiler will not show any warnings.

Thank you for the suggestion.